# Sharepoint filtered drop down list depending on group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter, groups, dropdown

I want to filter a drop down list within a list, depending on which group the user is bound to. Let's say that one group is called "green". The drop down list will originally have all different types of colour shades; light green, purple, blue, dark blue etc.

So when a user bound to the group "green" wants to add an item into that list, he/she will only see different shades of green in that drop down list.

This should be possible with look up fields since both these coloumns exist in other lists on that web page. Though, I cannot seem to get it working and would therfore appreciate some help.

Using SP 2010.

Edit 2014-08-06 13:35 : I've done everything that you mentioned except inheriting the list permissons. I do not want to do that since I don't see how that would effect the end results. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Give specific permissions for the items in the list which the lookup field looks up in. Set group Green to be the only ones with read permissions on all the items in the list with the shade of green and they should only be able to see those in the lookup field.

Comment: Can I use contribute permissions instead of read?

Comment: And should I add all the groups into the list permissions?

Comment: @Ponteee Yes you can use Contribute instead. You should only add the groups to the Items, not the list. Let the list inherit permissions, but break inheritance on the Items and add the groups individually.